# Is it possible to use plants as a medium to store data? By what data structure?

Tags: data-structures, graphs

my question is simple.
Is it possible to use plants as a medium to store data?

My opinion is: Possible, but we need to solve, how to distinguish 2 states. 
Duplication and CRC of stored DATA is quiet simple. Growing new plants is easiest possibility, but we need to create unit, which will take care about raid and duplicating informations between all plants.

Could there be a different data-structure? What is a potential of storing data into plants? What about security? How would you write data into plants without losing that information?

No, this is not a joke. Think about it. It grows everywhere, it is protected against water, cold, wet, dry, magnetic field, shaking and so on.

Try to remember, you can use your own garden as a datastore for your music, films and data. Or just use public garden to share media, photographs, messages or opinions by connecting remotely to plants.

Comment: Could plants die in a sudden?

Comment: ... plants already store and share beautiful photographs and relaxing music ... just look at them or listen to the sound of their leaves ... :-) :-)

Comment: Have you considered lower level storage? — I.e.: quantum? [**The information capacity of a single photon**](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.1427) *Full disclosure: I received an acknowledgement for this paper*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you propose sounds like it would be quite error laden, as plants are not necessarily independent, and those grown in the same area of the same species might share a common root system, so what you might consider redundancy is not a guarantee that your data will be preserved.  I would also venture to say that it's rare for a plant to be hardy against cold weather, and especially against something like an herbicide.

What you might consider is the concept of [biocomputing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biocomputers) and, more specifically, [DNA computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_computing), which uses the ordering of the base pairs to store and manipulate information.  The field is still in its infancy, but Turing machine-like behavior has been achieved, and in some cases basic algorithms can be implemented (e.g., the Hamiltonian path problem as cited in the Wikipedia article).